# where should session_destroy() code be placed?

Tags: php, session, logout

I have read several questions on stackoverflow about sessions and never found an answer to this :-)

That session_start() should be placed before any other code - even before the html tag is emphasized by everyone who responds to session questions. I am learning PHP mostly through this site and building my first php website as I go. I have understood all about unset, destroy and clear other than where they should be placed on the page.

I know this must be a very basic question but after four days of reading answers about logout and not finding it, am getting a little desperate.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter whether you write the code in top or bottom. What you have to do is when the logout button is clicked then logout() function should be called and inside that function this code should be there. You can also call another php file named logout.php with just this much code in it

Answer (score 0):

`session_destroy` should be placed in your logout page like this to destroy session of user

```
session_start(); // start session
session_destroy(); // destroy the current session of user
echo "You are logged out"; // place here greetings that user is logged out
// you can also redirect user to your login page
```

Answer (score 0):

You should unset the session variable which you have initialized and also use session_destroy() in the logout button action.

```
   function logout() {
          unset($_SESSION['username']);
          session_destroy();
   }
```

Comment: As I said - I am just a beginner. I have understood the functions, how they work etc. What I have not understood is WHERE on the page do these functions go? Do they go at the top pf each page that has a logout button? And does the session_start() also go at the top of each page?

Comment: It does not matter whether you write the code in top or bottom. What you have to do is when the logout button is clicked then logout() function should be called and inside that function this code should be there. You can also call another php file named logout.php with just this much code in it.

Comment: Thanks khushalbokadey! That is exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

Before going to answer about placing session_destroy(), you might have know difference between unset($_SESSION['username']) and session_destroy. If you want to destroy whole registered session then you can use session_destroy and if you want to destroy particular register session then you should unset($_SESSION['username']).For your answer, Write the below code in your logout page:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();//destroy all registered session
header('location:login.php');
?>
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

usually we add code for close session in logout.php page and then redirected to login page.
logout.php page has the following few lines

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:login.php');
?>
```